# Google Chart HTML positioning

Tags: html, css

[image]

I'm trying to put three google pie charts in a row. I have the set the css inline for now. For some reason the third chart goes to the next line. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.column-left{ float: left; width: 33%; } 
.column-right{ float: right; width: 33%; } 
.column-center{ display: inline-block; width: 33%; }
```

This worked for me

Answer (score 1):

First of all, why are you trying to position absolute some of them and then the other one not ? 
Focus on one way to position your elements. In this case I would either float them, or inline-block' "them".

Try adding the following to each one of them, or replace it with the following:

```
style="height:auto; width:30%; display:inline-block; margin-right:1%;"
```

Just a quick fix that should do the job.

Comment: Sorry. I'm not the best when it comes to CSS. But I looked up a solution, and what I posted above worked for me!

Comment: there are always 100way to do 1 thing :)
but again, try adding display:inline-block; to all of them with a width of 30%.
If you float you have to clear the float afterwards, otherwise youll get positioning problems with next elements

Comment: luckily, this is the only thing I have to display on the page. Other than a table underneath. The table already displays properly, like the way I want it to. Thanks for all your help though!